# Make: prerequisites in variable - secondexpansion

Tags: makefile

I would like to define a generic makefile that can be included by different makefiles like this (where a source t.c is compiled into t.o and archived in libl.a):

**Makefile:**

```
LIBS := libl
OBJS_libl := t
include c.mk
```

**c.mk:**

```
ALIBS  := $(LIBS:%=%.a)
.SECONDEXPANSION:
all : $(ALIBS)
%.a : $$(patsubst %,%.o,$$(OBJS_$$(patsubst %.a,%,$$(@F))))
    ar crs $@ $(patsubst %,%.o,$(OBJS_$(@F:%.a=%)))
%.o : %.c
    gcc -c $(@F:%.o=%.c) -o $@
```

The goal is that the prerequisites of the rule %.a expand as t.o for libl.a

This seems to work for explicit rules (if I replace %.a by libl.a) but not for implicit rules.

```
=> make: *** No rule to make target `libl.a', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Can I achieve this and how please?

[Edit] The goal indeed is to have in the same directory several libraries like libl.a, each made with some of the objects:

```
LIBS := libl1 libl2
OBJS_libl1 := t1 u1 
OBJS_libl2 := t2 u2
```

Comment: Whats wrong with `libl.a: t.o` in `Makefile`?

Comment: This would lead to define the dependancy twice in the makefile:
"libl.a: t.o" and "OBJS_libl := t". This raises maintenance issues.

Comment: Moreover this does not work: it only compiles t.c as t.o but does not archive.

Answer (score 0):

**Makefile:**

```
LIBS := libl.a
$(LIBS): t.o

include c.mk
```

**c.mk:**

```
%.a:
    ar crs $@ $^

%.o : %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

**EDIT:**

```
LIBS := libl1.a libl2.a
$(LIBS):
libl1.a : t1.o u1.o 
libl2.a : t2.o u2.o
```

Anything else?

Comment: This does not apply when several libraries each depend on some objects. I modified the question to clarify this aspect.